# DataSource in separate class- cellForRowAt indexPath not called

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, uitabbarcontroller, datasource

I want to implement the dataSource in a separate class. 
My implementation does seem to work here

This is my **UITableViewController**

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var itemsTableView: UITableView!
    let loginManager = LoginManager.shared
    let preferences = UserDefaultsManager.shared
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
    var delegate: PreferencesDelegate?

    let apiClient = ApiClient.shared

    var timer:Timer?
    var count: Int = 10

    var items:[Item]? {
        didSet {
            let dataSource = ItemDataSource(items: items!)
            tableView.dataSource = dataSource
            tableView.reloadData()
            //itemsTableView.dataSource = self
            //itemsTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureView()
    }

    func configureView() {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "You are logged in"
        apiClient.getData { (items) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.items = items
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            //seconds delay before starting timer
            self.runTimer()
        }
    }

    func runTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(MasterViewController.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func updateTimer() {
        if count > 0 {
            count -= 1
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "session will expire in \(count) seconds"
        }

        if count == 0 {
            preferences.clear()
            pushToLoginVC()
            timer?.invalidate()
        }
    }


    func pushToLoginVC() {
        let navigationCoordinator = NavigationCoordinator(window: appDelegate!.window!!)
        navigationCoordinator.setRoot(id: "LoginVC")
        delegate?.getCurrentUser()
    }
}
```

This is the **DataSource** Class

```
class ItemDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {


    private var items: [Item]
    init(items: [Item]) {
        self.items = items
        super.init()
    }


    // MARK: - Data Source
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("configure cell triggered")
        let itemCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "itemCell", for: indexPath) as! ItemViewCell

        let item = items[indexPath.row]
        let cellViewModel = ItemViewModel(item: item)
        itemCell.configure(viewModel: cellViewModel)

        return itemCell
    }

    // MARK: - Helper
    func item(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> Item {
        return items[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

the cell identifier is set "itemCell"
the custom class is also set "ItemViewCell"

**to assign the datasource. I initialize the datasource with the items
I put breakpoint and I have noticed that **cellForRowAt indexPath** is never called.**

the data are read from a json files. the array is not empty. it was tested.
tableView.dataSource is not nil. the app does not crash
the main issue is cellForRowAt indexPath. I Cannot seem to figure. I can keep all the datasource methods in the same MasterViewController, although I really would like to keep the datasource methods out for a better code quality mostly when the viewcontroller becomes large

Any idea someone ?

Comment: `dataSource` property of `UITableView` is `weak` (`weak var dataSource: UITableViewDataSource? { get set }`). And yours is a local variable. It wouldn't surprise me that it's released to soon. Do `var dataSource: ItemDataSource?` after `var delegate: PreferencesDelegate?` and call it then `dataSource = ItemDataSource(items: items!)` instead of `let dataSource = ItemDataSource(items: items!)`

Comment: Like @Larme said, datasource has local scope to your didSet. You can make datasource an instance variable of UITableViewController to retain it.

Comment: it worked thanks a lot!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

update to my question :

as per the answers I received, I have added **var dataSource:ItemDataSource** as a strong ref.

if dataSource is local, dataSource is weak and will not be retained

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var itemsTableView: UITableView!
    let loginManager = LoginManager.shared
    let preferences = UserDefaultsManager.shared
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
    var delegate: PreferencesDelegate?

    let apiClient = ApiClient.shared

    var timer:Timer?
    var count: Int = 10
    **var dataSource:ItemDataSource?**

    var items:[Item]? {
        didSet {
            **dataSource = ItemDataSource(items: items!)**
            tableView.dataSource = dataSource
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configureView()
    }

    func configureView() {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "You are logged in"
        apiClient.getData { (items) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.items = items
            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            //seconds delay before starting timer
            self.runTimer()
        }
    }

    func runTimer() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(MasterViewController.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func updateTimer() {
        if count > 0 {
            count -= 1
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "session will expire in \(count) seconds"
        }

        if count == 0 {
            preferences.clear()
            pushToLoginVC()
            timer?.invalidate()
        }
    }


    func pushToLoginVC() {
        let navigationCoordinator = NavigationCoordinator(window: appDelegate!.window!!)
        navigationCoordinator.setRoot(id: "LoginVC")
        delegate?.getCurrentUser()
    }
}
```